# Apply a git patch directly from GUI and commit to a branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, diff, patch

I currently have a patch (generated using `git diff`) that I want to apply to a repo. But due to certain limitations, I am unable to pull the repo locally. But I have full access of the repo via the gitlab GUI. I can create branch, generate merge request, etc. Is it possible to apply the said diff via the GUI to create a branch, assuming there is no conflict.

(I know I can edit individual files and commit it but I have multiple files and I want to apply just the diff and not risk copy and paste errors.)

Comment: Can you precise the problem with the pull? Do you have cloned repo? You cannot pull or you cannot fetch at all?